# Which row in my sectioned tableview?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, tableview

In one hand, I've got a plist in witch the root key is an array with 12 items.
In the second hand, i've got a sectioned tableview (with 3 sections MOTIF-COULEUR-OTHER)
What i want is that the tableview display correctly the datas in the sections.
in the first section i want to have items 0,1,2,3 of my plist
in the second section i want to have items 4,5,6,7,8,9,10 of my plist
in the last section i want to have the items 11 & 12

May be it's really simple, but it just made me crasy

her's my RootViewController.h & .m

the .h

```
//
//  RootViewController.h
//  FichesRaces
//
//  Created by a3116b on 28/05/11.
//  Copyright 2011 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> {
        NSArray *tabWebSites;


}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *tabWebSites;








@end
```

the .m

```
//
//  RootViewController.m
//  FichesRaces
//
//  Created by a3116b on 28/05/11.
//  Copyright 2011 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import "RootViewController.h"
#import "CatsList.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@implementation RootViewController
@synthesize tabWebSites;







- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Charger le fichier .plist dans un tableau que l'on appelera  arrayFromFile
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"cats" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSDictionary *dictFromFile = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSArray *arrayFromFile = [dictFromFile objectForKey:@"Root"];

    // Créons un tableau temporaire que nous allons remplir avec un objet Website par NSDictionnary contenu dans le fichier .plist
    // Notez l'utilisation de NSEnumerator pour parcourir un tableau
    NSMutableArray *websitesToAdd = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSEnumerator *enumerator = [arrayFromFile objectEnumerator];
    NSDictionary *anObject;
    while ((anObject = [enumerator nextObject])) {
        CatsList *cl = [[CatsList alloc] initWithDictionaryFromPlist: anObject];
        [websitesToAdd addObject: cl];
        [cl release];
    }

    // Remplir la propriété tabWebSites avec le contenu du NSMutableArray précédent
    self.tabWebSites = [NSArray arrayWithArray:websitesToAdd];

    // Gestion de la mémoire : pour chaque alloc, n'oubliez pas le release qui va avec !
    [websitesToAdd release];
    [arrayFromFile release];
}




- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}



- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    if ( section == 0 ) return @"Les Motifs";
    if ( section == 1 ) return @"Les Couleurs";
    if ( section == 2 ) return @"Bon à Savoir";

    return @"";

   // return [sectionHeaders objectAtIndex:section];
}






// Customize the number of sections in the table view.
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return 3;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    switch (section) {
        case 0:
            return 4;
            break;

        case 1:
            return 13;
            break;

        default:
            return 3;
            break;
    }

   }





// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    if (indexPath.section == 2) {
        CellIdentifier = @"cell";
    }


    // Les cellules sont mises en cache pour accélérer le traitement, sous l'identifiant "Cell",
    // on essaie récupère ce modèle de cellule s'il est déjà en cache
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Si on n'a pas réussi à sortir une cellule du cache, on crée un nouveau modèle de cellule
    // et on l'enregistre dans le cache
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];



     /*    (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row ==0);
         (indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 5);
         (indexPath.section == 2 && indexPath.row == 13);*/

   /*     //-----------------------------------------------

        NSUInteger sectionNumber = [indexPath section];
        NSUInteger rowNumber = [indexPath row];  

        // determine the correct row.
        // it will be restarted from 0 every time, and as
        // we're just loading in from one array, we need to
        // offset it by the right amount depending on the section.
        //  int sectionNumber = indexPath.row;
        if ( sectionNumber == 0 ) rowNumber = 4;
        if ( sectionNumber == 1 ) rowNumber = +5;
        if ( sectionNumber == 2 ) rowNumber = +18;


        //-----------------------------------------------   */


    }





    // On récupère l'objet Website qui correspon à la ligne que l'on souhaite afficher
    CatsList *cl = [self.tabWebSites objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // On configure la cellule avec le titre du site et sa description
    cell.textLabel.text = cl.TITLE;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = cl.DESCRIPTION;


    //important ajouter signalisation sinon APP REFUSE

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    // On renvoie la cellule configurée pour l'affichage
    return cell;
}



/*- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.section == 3) {
        return nil;
    }
    return indexPath;
}*/





- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{



    DetailViewController *detailVC = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    detailVC.CL = [self.tabWebSites objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailVC animated:YES];
    [detailVC release];
}






- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Relinquish ownership any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];

    // Relinquish ownership of anything that can be recreated in viewDidLoad or on demand.
    // For example: self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Thanks, your answers are very useful for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should tweak your data source (the NSArray you build from the plist) into managing the different sections you have. For example, instead of doing:

```
// On récupère l'objet Website qui correspon à la ligne que l'on souhaite afficher
CatsList *cl = [self.tabWebSites objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

you could do:

```
CatsList *cl = [self.tabWebSites objectAtIndex:[self linearIndexFromIndexPath:indexPath]];
```

where `linearIndexFromIndexPath:` would be defined, e.g., like this:

```
- (NSUInteger)linearIndexFromIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
    NSUInteger result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < indexPath.section ; i++) {
         result += [self numberOfSectionsInTableView:self.tableView];
    }
    return result + indexPath.row;
}
```

or something similar. Notice that in my implementation, I decided not to hard code the number of rows in each section, but of retrieving them using the delegate method. This makes the code more complex, but more resilient to changes.

Comment: This is great observation. I totally missed the row value is different when sections are involved. Would have upvoted +10 if that was possible.

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain to print the right number of row for each section ?
With the information you gave, I would print this.
Maybe there is some others mistakes, but that's a start.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    switch (section) {
        case 0:
            return 4;
            break;

        case 1:
            return 7;
            break;

        default:
            return 2;
            break;
    }
}
```