# Linear counting of rows in sectioned tableview

Tags: xcode, count, row, tableview

I have a sectioned tableview where the number of sections and number of rows is dynamic. Data is given to each row from different arrays and dictionaries. I would like to get the number of the row by **counting any rows in any section before the current row** when calling `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` . I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6817895/975799) but gives wrong results.
I guess that there should be a way to get a linear counting...

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:
In `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section`
i added:

```
NSString *numberOfRowsInSectionString = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"Section%i",section];
            [numberOsRowsArray addObject:numberOfRowsInSectionString];
```

When i need to know the number of the row i am:

```
NSString *currentSectionString = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"Section%i",indexPath.section];
    [numberOsRowsArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
    NSUInteger indexOfTheObject = [numberOsRowsArray indexOfObject:currentSectionString]+indexPath.row;
```